# Oryx: How to `inverse` a JAX function with additional parameters

Tags: python, jax, oryx

I would like to use the package [Oryx](https://github.com/jax-ml/oryx) to invert an affine transformation written in JAX. The transformation maps `x->y` and depends on a set of adjustable parameters (which I call `params`). Specifically, the affine transformation is defined as:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp

def affine(params, x):
  return x * params['scale'] + params['shift']

params = dict(scale=1.5, shift=-1.)
x_in = jnp.array(3.)
y_out = affine(params, x_in)
```

I would like to invert `affine` wrt to input `x` as a function of  `params`. Oryx has a function `oryx.core.inverse` to invert JAX functions. However, inverting a function with parameters, like this:

```py
import oryx

oryx.core.inverse(affine)(params, y_out)
```

doesn't work (`AssertionError: length mismatch: [1, 3]`), presumably because `inverse` doesn't know that I want to invert `y_out` but not `params`.
What is the most elegant way to solve this problem for all possible values (i.e., as a function) of `params` using `oryx.core.inverse`?
I find the [inverse docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/oryx/api_docs/python/oryx/core/inverse) not very illuminating.

**Update**:
Jakevdp gave an excellent suggestion for a given set of `params`. I've clarified the question to indicate that I am wondering how to define the inverse *as a function of* `params`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by closing over the static parameters, for example using `partial`:

```py
from functools import partial
x = oryx.core.inverse(partial(affine, params))(y_out)

print(x)
# 3.0
```

Edit: if you want a single inverted function to work for multiple values of `params`, you will have to return `params` in the output (otherwise, there's no way from a single output value to infer all three inputs). It might look something like this:

```py
def affine(params, x):
  return params, x * params['scale'] + params['shift']

params = dict(scale=1.5, shift=-1.)
x_in = jnp.array(3.)
_, y_out = affine(params, x_in)

_, x = oryx.core.inverse(affine)(params, y_out)
print(x)
# 3.0
```

Comment: If, for example, my `params` change every iteration in a loop. Would I then define a separate inverse function for every set of `params` (i.e., every iteration)? Or is there a way to define an inverse as a function of `params`?